# Footer is not Sticking to the Bottom of the Page only while Initial Page Loading

Tags: html, css, loading, footer

The Problem which I am facing is, My Page Footer is very much on its position, but it doesn't come on Position when very 1st the page is loaded.
But as soon as I re-size the Browser window, OR do any activity like: navigate to another page and come back to the initial page, OR even when I open the debugger; the footer come to its place at the very bottom !!!

I want to make it appear on the bottom, on even initial load of the page.

here is the HTML:

```
<div>
  <div id="header">
  <div id="container">
  <div id="footer">
</div>
```

here is the necessary CSS which I've included:

```
#header {
min-height: 75px;
}

#container {
height: 100%;
}

#footer {
clear: both;
height: 20px;
background-color: #F8F8F8;
border-top: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
color: #777777;
font-size: 11px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide code, otherwise your question is useless.

Comment: You also need to provide the HTML code and any javascript that you use to display elements in your page, and also your browser version perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

We can't say why this is happening without seeing your markup, only we can suggest that you can try

```
#footer {
position:absolute;
box-sizing:border-box;
left:0px;
bottom: 0px !important;
height: 30px;
width:100%;
background-color: #F8F8F8;
border-top: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
color: #777777;
font-size: 11px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: There is no need for Markup, as it is simply 3 <div> consist of above 3 IDs each, and a single div containing all 3 <div>.

though this css didn't work!
because using Position property, My footer get shrink.. and if I give width: 100%, it adds a horizontal scroll-bar to my application.

Answer (score 0):

Try [stickyfooter](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/), without the html markup the css doesn't give us much to go on, but sticky footer is a great solution to keep your footer on the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your footer:

```
#footer {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```